# Как к swagger 2 добавить http basic аутентификацию

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

Подскажите, как реализовать, чтобы перед тем, как пользоваться сваггером, он запрашивал авторизацию?

Простое spring boot приложение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все сервисы обычно за чем-нибудь скрывают и не выставляют наружу. Я обычно использую nginx примерно с таким конфигом:

```
upstream swagger_server {
        server localhost:8021; # порт, на котором крутится свагер
}

server {
    listen 8020 default_server;

    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.swagger_htpasswd; # тут зашифрованный пароль


    server_name swagger.hehehe.com;

    location / {
                    client_max_body_size 5M;
                    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                    proxy_pass          http://swagger_server;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }

    charset utf-8;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/swagger_server.access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/swagger_server.error.log;
}
```

Для генерации пароля:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.swagger_htpasswd my_user
```